# Command into the VM that runs a Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm new to Azure DevOps pipeline, currently nothing works,

I am using Azure DevOps Service with the hosted agent from Azure. Can I some how keep that VM that runs Azure DevOps pipeline running? I want to test my `azure-pipeleines.yml` file in the faster way via access this VM by terminal.

Comment: Hosted agent is a public resource controlled by MS, you can not make more customized services for it. The suggestion is to create your own agent, then you will get more power:https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-set-up-a-private-agent-in-visual-studio-tea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access Microsoft-hosted agents via terminal. They are assigned for your build and after they go to pool again to use by someone else.

If you want to access to agents you must have your own. You can create them on your own Azure VM's for instance.

Answer (score 0):

He is right, hosted agents are just containers which are disposed when the pipeline is done. if you want to debug, like checking files or what it's not working, you need to have a self hosted agent. it can be on your own computer for debugging and you use the hosted one during normal processing